# Refresh Image Style in Drupal Commerce on Add To Cart Attributes Refresh (D7)

Tags: commerce, media

I'm building a t-shirt website, and I'm looking into having the customer be able to choose certain shirt attributes such as hoodie/t-shirt, shirt color, etc.

Using imagecache actions, I've looked into setting up a separate image style for each variation type (such as black hoodie) which then renders the shirt design onto a template for a black hoodie. I've gotten this to work as individual image styles. I've looked into the solution proposed [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65991/how-to-alter-image-style-based-on-product-custom-attribute) (in the second answer) to create an image style called 'clothing' that then runs a 'custom action' image effect to determine the image style to actually render. Using the code in the linked answer, I was able to modify it to do a check on:

```
$image_context['entity']
```

and grab the tid of the attribute (such as shirt color) and then run a `taxonomy_term_load` to check the attribute name.

I've gotten this to work (tentatively), and I can handle the base-level PHP to do the comparing and logic to check the attributes. The problem that I'm having is that when I change an attribute (such as shirt color), the `$image_context['entity']` object is not updated and/or the image style is not re-rendered.

How can I cause the image style to be re-processed when a user changes an attribute on the add to cart form? I know little on this, but I've read that I could possibly us a custom module and `hook_commerce_cart_attributes_refresh_alter`.

I don't know much about the syntax of this function, and I don't know how to trigger a change to the `$image_context['entity']` object and/or refresh the image style. In a worst-case-scenario, I would even be willing to change the value of the object and reload the page, but this would not be ideal.

Can I just `dpm` the values from inside `hook_commerce_cart_attributes_refresh_alter` and grab the new values, and set them accordingly inside `$image_context['entity']`? i.e. would the image style automatically be re-triggered because the new product image would be grabbed?

Is this possible?